# Rcmd check and wrong ZLIB1.dll: How to set environment variables for Rcmd specifically?

Tags: r, windows, lotus-notes, zlib

I'm running into a weird problem when I want to check (`Rcmd check`) an R package. Every few steps of the checking process, I receive the following error message:

[image: zlib_error]

I can close the message and everything works as expected, but it's pretty annoying to close the message since it pops up every few seconds.

The error stems from fact that R also comes with it's own `zlib1.dll` (`C:\Program Files\R\Tcl\bin64\zlib1.dll`) but finds the one from IBM Notes.

This seems to be connected with the `PATH` environment variable. In `PATH`, `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\ZLIB1.dll` appears earlier than the R related directories. I can't change that, since I hhave only rights to alter the user-specific environment variables.

Is there a possibility to tell R specifically, where to search for `ZLIB1.dll`?

---

### EDIT:

If I change the directory from which RStudio is started, the error does not occur any more, but RStudio does not remember the last used project.

[image: workaround]

Comment: PATH is a user-specific environment variable. You can change this in user accounts via control panel. (Or indeed directly within R)

Comment: That's not correct. As a user, I can only change the part which appears when I type `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('path', 'user')` in PowerShell. But `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('path')` contains additional entries before.

Comment: Does it behave differently if you make C:\Program Files\R\Tcl\bin64\ your current directory?

Comment: Is the path entry for Notes set by an organisation policy? I ask because it seems to be non-standard - I have IBM Notes 9.0.1 installed and don't have a path entry for it.
If not an organisation policy, then maybe later Notes versions set the path, or maybe some other app did that.

Comment: Yes, the Notes PATH is set by an org policy. Several other tools need the Notes PATH entry to interact with some Notes databases. Notes resets it's PATH at every startup.